# Creating raster with defined value range in R

Tags: r

I want to create a raster with min value -1 and max value of 1. The values can be distributed in any form and the extent and resolution can also be random. I just want my raster to have values between -1 and 1.

I want this for purpose of symbology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a 2x1 raster with a -1 and a 1 in it.

```
> r = raster(matrix(c(-1,1),1,2))
> range(r[])
[1] -1  1
```